# Printing elements of list of objects

Tags: java, list

//contacts class

```
package com.company;

public class Contacts {
    private String name;
    private String number;

    public Contacts(String name, String number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public  String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
}


//class Phone
package com.company;

import java.rmi.StubNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Phone {
    private ArrayList<Contacts> contacts1 = new ArrayList<Contacts>();


    public void addContact(String name, String numbers) {
        Contacts contacts = new Contacts(name, numbers);
        contacts1.add(contacts);

    }

    public void printContacts() {
        for (int i = 0; i < contacts1.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(contacts1.); // >>> how to print elements (name and phone number)

        }
    }
}
```

Here I tried to print a list of contacts including name and phone number but could not handle how to iterate over a list of objects. How  can I print name and phoneNumber using printContacts() method in Phone class?
Thanks

Comment: have your IDE generate a `toString` method for the `Contacts` class and then use `System.out.println(contacts1);`. I would also suggest you rename `Contacts` (plural) to `Contact`.

Comment: You need to override `toString()` in `Contacts` and in `for` print `contacts1.get(i).toString()`

Answer (score 1):

You would do:

```
System.out.println(contacts1.get(i));
```

but that would just give Contacts@somenumber, so you will need to add a toString() method to the Contacts class.
In the contacts class, add a function that looks like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name + ": " + number;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Override `toString` method in your class Contacts to return a string representation of your class object (for e.g. json string). `System.out.println` prints string returned by this method.

```
public class Contacts {
  private String name;
  private String number;

  ...

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "{\"name\": \"" + name + "\", \"number\": \"" + number + "\"}";
  }
}
```

P.S. If you are using one the java IDEs, check out the implementation of `println` method in file `PrintStream.java` in java source code. Java IDEs provides this feature of code navigation in your project by which you can actually navigate through source code of Java itself.